# Draw n ellipses separated by a certain distance

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I want to accomplish something like in C#:

[image]

To do so I was thinking on

```
1. get center of canvas
2. draw center ellipse using center
3. taking the center ellipse, do two loops, one to draw ellipses that are above center, and other loop to draw ellipses that are under center
(I assigned same `x` to all and changed `y` to set ellipses positions)
4. Everytime a cicle passed, update size (incrise it) and `Y` multiplying it by size and its indes in loop
```

I am using 15 as size of ellipse (width and height), then for each ellipse I increase it 1.4 times the size.

The code is:

```
    SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    int ellipsesAbove = 5;
    int ellipsesUnder = 5;
    double size = 20;
    double x_center = 50;
    double y_center = 50;

    //------ Create center Ellipse
    Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
    e.Height = size;
    e.Width = size;
    e.StrokeThickness = 1;
    e.Stroke = color;
    e.Fill = color;
    e.Margin = new Thickness(x_center, y_center, 1, 1);
    this.Children.Add(e);
    //----loop to create above ellipses 
    //I SUBSTRACT SIZE IN Y
    for (int i = 2; i <= ellipsesAbove; i++)
    {
        Ellipse ac = new Ellipse();
        ac.Height = size;
        ac.Width = size;
        ac.StrokeThickness = 1;
        ac.Stroke = color;
        ac.Fill = color;
        double x = x_center;
        double y = y_center - (size * i); 
        ac.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 1, 1);
        this.Children.Add(ac);
        size *= 1.4;
    }
    //reset size
    size = 15;
    //-------loop to create under ellipses
    //I ADD SIZE IN Y
    for (int j = 2; j <= ellipsesUnder; j++)
    {
        Ellipse uc = new Ellipse();
        uc.Height = size;
        uc.Width = size;
        uc.StrokeThickness = 1;
        uc.Stroke = color;
        uc.Fill = color;
        double x = x_center;
        double y = y_center + (size * j); 
        uc.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 1, 1);
        this.Children.Add(uc);
        size *= 1.4;
    }
```

However I am getting unaligned and poorly distanced ellipses
[image]

How to improve code or loops to get correct result?

Comment: Better draw Paths with EllipseGeometries (for easier centering) and add them to a Canvas, where you set their positions by the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are making things way, way harder for yourself by not using data binding. Just create a view model to hold your ellipse data:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public IList<object> Items { get; private set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            var size = 5.0 * Math.Pow(1.4, Math.Abs(i-6));
            this.Items.Add(new { X = 50 + i * 25 - size / 2, Y = 50 + i * 25 - size / 2, Radius = size });
        }
    }
}
```

Code-wise that's it, you've created enough data for a view to bind to. You're rendering a list of items, so create an ItemsControl. You want to draw on a Canvas, so set that as its ItemsPanel. You want each element to be an ellipse, so set that as the ItemTemplate. And finally set the style properties to position and size each element:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Radius}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Radius}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very good Answer @Mark, However I am actually trying to do this using only code behind, so the `ItemsControl ` part would be replace by adding manually all ellipses as in your creation loop right?

Comment: More-or-less, yes. But the point of my answer was to show how much easier it is when you do things properly. The ability to manipulate view controls directly in code-behind was added to WPF in order to facilitate the transition from WinForms, it's not how WPF was designed to be used itself (in some 7 or 8 years of working with WPF I've never once seen a case where it was preferable to do so).

Answer (score 0):

First, when you reset the size variable you need to reset it to 20 instead of 15.  Next, when you offset your circles you need to offset the x-coordinate the same as your y-coordinate.  Margins act funny with Canvases.  I used a Grid and it works okay.  I think the important thing is that you realize that the x-coordinate also has to be offset.

Comment: You do it exactly the same way as the y-coordinate:  double x = x_center - (size * i); for the first block and double x = x_center + (size * i); for the second block.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the something like the **first** picture you showed us, have a look at this code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ellipse_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int pic_size_x = 500;
            const int pic_size_y = 500;

            Bitmap pBitmap = new Bitmap(pic_size_x, pic_size_y);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pBitmap))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                const int num_circles = 12;
                for (int i = 0; i < num_circles; i++)
                {
                    //Compute the X/Y center
                    int x = i * pic_size_x / num_circles;
                    int y = i * pic_size_y / num_circles;

                    int radius = Math.Abs((int) ((x - 250)/(float)250 * 40)) + 10;

                    //Draw a circle there
                    g.FillPie(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), x, y, radius, radius, 0, 360);
                }
            }
            pBitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\<yournamehere>\Desktop\Test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces

[image: circles]

I'll explain the code a little. The mathematical concept is, that the center of each circle is **equally** spaced. So really I have a curve / a line going from the upper left corner to the lower right corner. The spacing is computed by the number of circles. Then, I set up a mathematical function to compute the radius of each circle. I want them to get bigger and smaller, but linerarly. I chose a absolute value function for that job. First, the x coordinate is shifted by `pic_size_x/2` to the left. After that, I'll divide it by that factor as well to get it between 0 and 1. After that, I'll multiply it by a constant factor sothat it get's bigger, then add 10 to it sothat the radius is never zero. If you look at that function in google, you'll see what I mean.

[image: func]

The code can now be easily modified to draw eclipses or whatever else you want.